# Regex to Split obj.method(obj.attr, obj.attr2)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm looking for a regex to split this kind of content :

```
obj.method(obj.attr,obj.attr2)
```

And I want the split to return an array :

```
["obj", "method(obj.attr, obj.attr2)"]
```

So, I can't split on "." because it will also split the content of the method attributs.

I have to split on the "." only if they are not between "(" and ")" I think.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks !

Comment: show the example the prevent you from using split on dot '.'

Comment: If I split on the dot '.' with this: "obj.method(obj.attr,obj.attr2)" it will return ["obj", "method(obj", "attr,obj", "attr2)"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to solve this with regex it's better to do with match instead of split.

For that you can use [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#balancing_group_definition) to count the number of open parenthesis.

For example you can get all the matched strings for this expression to give you the desired result:

```
(?x)                    # allow comments and ignore spaces
(?:
    [^.()]+             # don't match .
    |
    \(
    (?:
        [^()]+          # in here . are allowed
    |   (?<open> \( )   # open++
    |   (?<-open> \) )  # open-- (as long as open > 0)
    )*
    (?(open) (?!) )     # fail if open > 0
    \)
)+
```

Comment: ManojRK solution's seems to work, but I will go for that if I'm having an issue

Comment: @abecker, just know that his solution doesn't work with any nested parenthesis.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, I finally used your solution ! Thanks a lot. Do you have any tips / good tutorials for practicing with Regex ?

Comment: @abecker, I can recommend reading through the .NET regex docs about every construct, and try them out. Not so many of them. There seem to be good examples in there. And I guess there are many tutorials out there and some good books too.

Answer (score 2):

This is the RegEx you must use

```
(\w+)\.(\w+\([^)]*\))
```

[image: Regular expression image]

Comment: `foo.bar(baz(foo.baz), que.bar)`

Comment: sorry for off topic, what software did you used to draw the illustration?

Comment: I used http://www.debuggex.com The site is very useful to debug RegEx and also generates possible matches from the RegEx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        string objAttr = "obj.method(obj.attr,obj.attr2)";

        var res = objAttr.Split('.');
        var obj = res[0];
        var methodCall = String.Join(".", res.Skip(1));
```

Output:

> obj
>   method(obj.attr,obj.attr2)